# How does a linux C/C++ system() command work?

Tags: linux, shell

Or, more specifically, does it use the default shell, or actually running the actual file. Example: `system("echo Hello, World!")`. Would this run using, lets say Bash, or would this run by telling to kernal to run a command? Also, is this on topic, or would this fit better somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man system` is your friend here. This is what is says on my system:

> The  system()  library  function uses fork(2) to create a child
> process that executes the shell command specified in command using
> execl(3)  as follows:
>
> ```
> execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Unfortunately, I was trying to get an east way to run commands using C++, without using a shell, if that makes sense. Regardless, thanks for the help!

Comment: Without a shell, you're going to have to manually invoke OS calls.  On Unix-like platforms, this means `fork()` to make a clone of yourself, then check its return code so the new process replaces itself with your external command (via one of the `exec()` calls).  If you need to set up a pipeline of commands or redirect I/O, there will be more things you need to do, in which case you may want to reconsider your desire to not use a shell.

Answer (score 1):

What POSIX says about this is the following:

> The system() function shall behave as if a child process were created using fork(), and the child process invoked the sh utility using execl() as follows:
>
> `execl(<shell path>, "sh", "-c", command, (char *)0);`
>
> where  is an unspecified pathname for the sh utility. It is unspecified whether the handlers registered with pthread_atfork() are called as part of the creation of the child process.

In other words, the entire command you give it is passed to `sh -c`.  On Linux, it always uses `/bin/sh`.  On some distros it will be bash, and others, such as Debian, may use another shell.  Debian uses dash by default, but allows the administrator to choose a different shell instead provided it meets certain criteria.